# iPhone App - Hide picker show keyboard and hide keyboard show picker

Tags: iphone, keyboard, picker

in the iPhone app, i have both the text field and picker in the same window. I want the picker popup to disappear when user clicks on textfield and keyboard appears. Similarly keyboard should disappear and picker popup should come up when user clicks on picker.
Any sample code?

Comment: If the picker disappears how does the user find it again?

Comment: I may have used wrong word. When you click the picker – the popup comes with the list. I am trying to hide that popup not the picker. In my case if the user clicks on textfield, the keyboard comes and then if the user clicks on picker – the popup also comes behind the keyboard. 
I want to hide keyboard when the picker popup comes, similarly hide picker popup when user clicks on textfield and keyboard opens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use textfielddidbeginEditing method. In which you can if condition for identifying textfield and on the basis of that return yes if you want to show keyboard and return no if you dont want to display keyboard. Here if you return no than keyboard will not display same time you can show your picker with your custom code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Dipak that certainly helps

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to listen for system notifications for the keyboard appearing.

In your controller, do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Then, just implement the method keyboardWillShow:(id)sender, and you'll have everything you need.

There's another notification for when the keyboard disappears, too.

If you then need to hide the keyboard, you need to call "resignFirstResponder" on whatever object that particular keyboard is associated with.